# Why can't opaque optics form a category?

Tags: ct.category-theory, haskell

The [`optics`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/optics-0.4/docs/Optics.html) Haskell package is an alternative to the famous [`lens`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens) package.

`lens` uses a van Laarhoven encoding, encoding lenses as functions. This means than not only do `lens` lenses form a category, but they actually compose using standard function composition. In other words, they can compose using the old-fashioned `.` operator, even before the `Category` typeclass.

`optics`, in contrast, defines lenses using opaque newtypes. It should still be possible to get access to composition via the `.` operator by defining a `Category` instance. However, `optics` doesn't do that, but instead defines a new `%` composition operator. [The docs](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/optics-0.4/docs/Optics.html) have this to say:

> The (.) operator from Control.Category cannot be used to compose optics [..] because it would not support type-changing optics or composing optics of different kinds.

and

> optics must use a different composition operator (%). Optic does not quite form a Category, thanks to type-changing optics.

This leaves me very puzzled. [It is well known](http://comonad.com/reader/2012/mirrored-lenses/) that `lens`' van Laarhoven lenses *do* support type-changing (polymorphic update), whilst still being a category by construction, via their underlying function type.

Can someone explain why it's impossible for `optics` lenses to form a category, even though they are functionally equivalent to van Laarhoven?

Is it possible to define lenses more opaque than `lens` whilst still forming a lawful category?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`optics` do form a category where the objects are `(Type, Type)`. However,
the `Optic` type is defined with

```
newtype Optic k is s t a b = ...
```

The domain and the codomain of `Optic` are curried into 4 type arguments `s t a b`, but the `Category` typeclass in Haskell requires the domain and the codomain to be the last two type arguments of the type constructor.

Alternatively, the `Optic` type can be defined with

```
newtype Optic k is (st :: (Type, Type)) (ab :: (Type, Type)) = ...
```

This allows a `Category` instance, however it is less user-friendly, since the user would need to use `DataKinds` tuples to specify the types.